# Связать два CSV файла по столбцу (с агрегацией)

Tags: python, csv

Суть данного скрипта в том, чтобы он вывел список значений из 2 файла, соответствующих значению id из первого файла. В итоге он выводит список лишь для самого первого id, а для остальных выдает пустой список "[ ]". Причем для каждого из этих id есть соответствующие значения, пустых списков там выводиться не должно. Что я не так делаю?

```
posts_table = open("posts.csv")
cat_rel_table = open("category_relationship.csv")

reader_1 = csv.DictReader(posts_table)
reader_2 = csv.DictReader(cat_rel_table)

def cat_name(post_id):
    cat_list = []
    for cat in reader_2:
        if cat['post_id'] == post_id:
            cat_list.append(cat['cat_id'])
    return cat_list

for post in reader_1:
    if (post['type'] == "8" and post['status'] == "1"):
        print(post['id'], cat_name(post['id']))
```

вот пример содержимого posts.csv:

```
"id","type","price","new_price","from_date","to_date","parent","created_at","author","featured","template","stock","view","status","barcode"
"84","8","117","0","0000-00-00 00:00:00","0000-00-00 00:00:00","0","2017-10-12 14:37:38","1","../uploads/posts/2017/10/1-10-r-c-audi-r8-v10-compl-6v.jpg","0","10","0","2",
"85","8","28","0","0000-00-00 00:00:00","0000-00-00 00:00:00","266","2017-10-12 17:41:45","1","../uploads/posts/2017/10/0011543346227-a.jpg","0","10","0","2",
"86","8","13","0","0000-00-00 00:00:00","0000-00-00 00:00:00","266","2017-10-19 10:38:06","1","../uploads/posts/2017/10/81XHlhvCsJL._SL1500_.jpg","0","10","0","2",
"87","8","28","0","0000-00-00 00:00:00","0000-00-00 00:00:00","266","2017-10-19 11:03:55","4","../uploads/posts/2017/10/cat-9-inch-big-builder-l&s-shaking-machine-vehicle-dump-truck--5AE442DA.zoom.jpg","0","10","0","1","11543346210"
"88","8","28","0","0000-00-00 00:00:00","0000-00-00 00:00:00","0","2017-10-19 11:05:59","1","../uploads/posts/2017/10/pTRUCA1-22577036_alternate1_enh-z6.jpg","0","10","0","2",
```

Пример category_relationship.csv

```
"id","type","cat_id","post_id","status"
"31","8","21","84","2"
"32","8","21","85","2"
"33","8","20","86","2"
"34","8","21","86","2"
"35","8","20","87","1"
"36","8","21","87","2"
"37","8","20","88","2"
"38","8","21","88","2"
```

Ожидаемый вывод: `{131: ['2', '11', '43', '45', '72', '5', '8', '44']}` (для каждого айдишника). Т.е. слева айдишник из первой таблицы, а справа список значений который скрипт получает из другой таблицы.

Comment: дополнил вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот теперь разобрался. У Вас, проблема в том, что конструкции `open("category_relationship.csv")` и `csv.DictReader` выдают объекты типа итератора, и после первого прохода курсор остается в конце, соответственно значений он более не возвращает, отсюда и пустой вывод при каждом следующем проходе.
Для того, чтобы этого избежать, нужно считывать данные из файла для каждого прохода. Получается вот так:

```
import csv

posts = csv.DictReader(open("posts.csv"))


def cat_list(post_id):
    return [item['cat_id'] for item in
            csv.DictReader(open("category_relationship.csv"))
            if item['post_id'] == post_id]


di = {post['id']: cat_list(post['id']) for post in posts
      if post['type'] == "8" and post['status'] == "1"}

# теперь словарь di можно использовать по своему усмотрению

print(di)

for key, val in di.items():
    print(key, val)
```

---

*Решение на основе предложения топикстртера:*

```
import csv

cat_file = open("category_relationship.csv")
category = csv.DictReader(cat_file)
posts = csv.DictReader(open("posts.csv"))  # Поскольку здесь только один проход, скомбинируем.


def cat_list(post_id):
    cat_file.seek(0)  # Возвращаем курсор в начальное положение.
    return [item['cat_id'] for item in
            category if item['post_id'] == post_id]


di = {post['id']: cat_list(post['id']) for post in posts
      if post['type'] == "8" and post['status'] == "1"}

# теперь словарь можно использовать по своему усмотрению

print(di)
for key, val in di.items():
    print(key, val)
```

Comment: Что-то типа этого: "131 ['2', '11', '43', '45', '72', '5', '8', '44']" (для каждого айдишника). Т.е. слева айдишник из первой таблицы, а справа список значений который скрипт получает из другой таблицы.

Comment: @KVM1L. Вопрос вывод добавьте, так быстрее и эффективней будет

Comment: причина найдена, как раз в этом она и заключалась. но решил я немного другим способом - установкой самого курсора в начало файла через `cat_rel_table.seek(0)` в каждом цикле. спасибо!

Comment: @KVM1L, Ваше решение гораздо элегантней. С Вашего позволения отредактирую ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Для подобных задач идеально подходит модуль [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd   #  pip install pandas

p = pd.read_csv(r'D:\temp\posts.csv')
c = pd.read_csv(r'D:\temp\category_relationship.csv')

res = (p.loc[(p['type']==8) & (p['status']==1), ['id']]
        .set_index('id')
        .join(c.groupby('post_id')['cat_id']
               .apply(lambda x: x.values.tolist())))
```

результат:

```
In [372]: p
Out[372]:
   id  type  price  new_price            from_date      ...      template  stock view  status       barcode
0  84     8    117          0  0000-00-00 00:00:00      ...             0     10    0       2           NaN
1  85     8     28          0  0000-00-00 00:00:00      ...             0     10    0       1           NaN
2  86     8     13          0  0000-00-00 00:00:00      ...             0     10    0       2           NaN
3  87     8     28          0  0000-00-00 00:00:00      ...             0     10    0       1  1.154335e+10
4  88     8     28          0  0000-00-00 00:00:00      ...             0     10    0       2           NaN

[5 rows x 15 columns]

In [373]: c
Out[373]:
   id  type  cat_id  post_id  status
0  31     8      21       84       2
1  32     8      21       85       2
2  33     8      20       86       2
3  34     8      21       86       2
4  35     8      20       87       1
5  36     8      21       87       2
6  37     8      20       88       2
7  38     8      21       88       2

In [374]: res
Out[374]:
      cat_id
id
85      [21]
87  [20, 21]

In [375]: res.to_dict()['cat_id']
Out[375]: {85: [21], 87: [20, 21]}
```